# How can I add weight units to my quantity in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a weight quantity input field on product pages that allow customer to change the item weight by clicking on a plus or minus buttons. For example, you want to buy 1.25kg of tomatoes. For that, you can just click the plus icon until it reaches 1.25kg or you can type 1.25 kg. [**Here is an example**](https://www.fruitxpress.ee/juurvi.../kirsstomat-lahtine.html) of what I am looking for *(this one does not have the ability to insert your quantity though)*.

Currently, I have used the plugins [WPC Product Quantity](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpc-product-quantity/) and [WooCommerce Price Per Unit PRO](https://codecanyon.net/item/price-per-unit-pro/25776274), but the problem is that it does not show the "kg" unit after the quantity number. You can have a look at that [**over here**](https://www.relyx.ee/toode/papaia/)

Is there a plugin or a custom code that I can insert to fix this issue?

**Note:** I have products, which use units "kg" and "tk". So the code/plugin should be able to fix this issue on a product basis. "tk" just means "piece" in Estonian.

Comment: Sorry but plugin recommendations are off topic in stackOverFlow. StackOverFlow is mostly for people asking for help on their provided code.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to change the quantity box from integer datatype to float/double datatype, So the customer can place float number like 0.25 or 0.5,

you can use `settype($var,"double");` in your code.

if the kg is not showing you also can use concatenate to add "kg" to your return value.

you return your value with concatenate by adding this to the end of your return value:

```
. " kg"
```